# Swapping JTextField contents

Tags: java, textfield

I have one Jframe which includes two TextFields and I want to exchange two integer numbers after clicking on exchange button.

Comment: `.getText()` and `.setText()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value from one text box and store it in the other.

> .getText() is used to get the value from the textbox.
>
> .setText() is used to set the value of a textbox.

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String temp = jTextField1.getText();
    jtextField1.setText(jTextField2.getText());
    jtextField2.setText(temp);
    
}                                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `JTextField`s use Strings this works pretty much everywhere.

```
String temp = text1.getText();
text1.setText(text2.getText());
text2.setText(temp);
```